# How do I fix error while running gaussian blur?

Tags: python, image-processing, filter, deep-learning, gaussian

I have written the following code to apply Gaussian filter to images inside a folder:

```
import cv2
import numpy
import os

directory = r'/path to image folder/'

for file in os.listdir(directory):
    src = cv2.imread(directory + file)
    # apply guassian blur on src image

    dst = cv2.GaussianBlur(src, (15, 15), cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT)

    # saving now
    cv2.imwrite(file + 'gua' + '.jpg', dst)
```

I am getting following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path to python code/sampling.py", line 11, in <module>
    dst = cv2.GaussianBlur(src, (15, 15), cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.2.0) /io/opencv/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:757: error: (-215:Assertion failed) dims <= 2 && step[0] > 0 in function 'locateROI'
```

How do I fix this error?

Thanks

Comment: Can you give image snippet, because it worked fine for me in my given image.

Comment: basically my images are some horizontally flipped images that I generated with python code. On top of that, I am adding this code. I do not have any idea why this error comes.

Comment: I suggest you to read official docs and see if something helps you here: https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_filtering/py_filtering.html#gaussian-filtering

Comment: Your directory likely contains files that cannot be read as an image. You need to add a test to verify that `imread` worked, if returns an empty array when it fails.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, how do I figure out what file causing this problem? all images look ok,

Comment: Add a test after `imread` to see if `src` is empty and write out the file name: `if not src: print(file)`. Now when you run the code you'll see which file it is failing on.

Comment: can you please explain it through the code, I would choose your answer if it works then.